# accessing multiple layout views from outside an activity or fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android and I am having trouble finding a way to solve my issue.  I have searched extensively but cannot seem to find a solution to my specific need.

I have an app that has a main activity with 9 different fragments.  8 of them are divided up between two ViewPagers.  I have a separate CalculateX Class that is not an activity or fragment.  Two of the fragments have a bunch of EditTexts and 7 of the others have a bunch of TextViews.

In the CalculateX class I need to get the user inputted info from the editTexts at once, do some calculations, then return them to the TextViews from the various other fragments.

I am failing to come up with a way to get references to the various layouts.  I thought about creating a reference variable inside of each fragment class, but after doing some reading it seems like that might cause a memory problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**Update 7-28-15**

Ok, so I have been working on this and have a partial solution.  Fragment1, that holds the editTexts, now has an interface to help communicate.

```
    public interface OnDisplayArmy {
    public void onReceivedCount(String count);
}
```

With in that fragment I also have an addTextChangedListener

```
  EditText barbText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.barbarian_amount);
    barbText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            CalculateAndDisplay testDisplay = new CalculateAndDisplay(v);
            String newCount = testDisplay.CalculateArmy();
            mDisplayCallback.onReceivedCount(newCount);
            Log.d("Distribute", "got to afterTextChanged");
        }
    });
```

That will fire my calculate class

```
public class CalculateAndDisplay {
View elixFragmentView;

public CalculateAndDisplay(View elixView) {
    elixFragmentView = elixView;
}

public String CalculateArmy() {
    EditText barbarianValue = (EditText) elixFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.barbarian_amount);
    String barbarianCount = String.valueOf(barbarianValue.getText());
    Log.d("Distribute", "got to CalculateArmy");
    return barbarianCount;
}
}
```

That class will perform the calculation and return the result back to the Fragment1 addTextChangedListener.  Then the mDisplayCallback.onReceivedCount() takes the value and passes it to the mainActivity.  The MainActivity implements the above interface and adds this method

```
  @Override
public void onReceivedCount(String count) {
    ElixBarracksOne elixBarracksOne = (ElixBarracksOne) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("elix_barracks_one");
    Log.d("Distribute", "got to onReceivedCount");
    if (elixBarracksOne != null) {
        elixBarracksOne.setArmyCount(count);
        Log.d("Distribute", "got to onRecievedCount if statement");
    }
}
```

**Second Update**
I fixed my previous issue by using

```
ElixBarracksOne elixBarracksOne = (ElixBarracksOne) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
            "android:switcher:"+R.id.barracks_pager+":0");
```

Instead of the above code.  This allows me to communicate with the Fragment2 and set the text, but once I start swiping through the fragments in the pager it disappears by the time I come back.  I am assuming this is because the fragment is destroyed and then recreated.

So now I need to know how to save the TextView values out of the onReceivedCount method.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Third Update**

Ok, so I am realizing that I am not going to be able to communicate with a fragment that is not in view.  So at this point I am thinking of storing the info into the database and have the fragments pull from there. Not sure if there is a listener that I can attach to the fragments that will trigger when the database is updated

Comment: Please post some of the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please add the errors ur getting and some more code as well

Comment: I decided to take different route and implemented a content provider.  This can be closed